# Can arrows() draw an arrow head only?

Tags: r, graphics

Is there a way to plot an arrow without its 'body' with the R graphics package?

```
plot(0, type="n", ann=FALSE, axes=FALSE, xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1))
arrows(x0=0.5, y0=0.2, x1=0.5, y1=0.9) # without the line '|'?
```

So I'm essentially interested in just plotting an arrow head (or also triangle, for example),
but it has to be with the R graphics package (base graphics). I was hoping to
avoid having to draw the arrow head on my own (would `segments()` be a good
way to do that?).

Comment: You can try to just make it very small: `arrows(x0=0.5, y0=0.9-(1e-3), x1=0.5, y1=0.9)`. I can't see it, at least....

Comment: That's a nice 'hack', exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot. Can you formulate it like an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this simple thing:

```
arrowhead <- function(x0, y0, x1, y1, length = 0.25, angle = 30,...){
    t = atan2(y1-y0, x1-x0)
    a1 = pi+t+angle*pi/180
    a2 = pi+t-angle*pi/180
    e1x = x1 + length*cos(a1)
    e1y = y1 + length*sin(a1)
    e2x = x1 + length*cos(a2)
    e2y = y1 + length*sin(a2)
    lines(c(e1x,x1,e2x),c(e1y,y1,e2y),...)
}
```

which could easily be improved. The big difference with `arrows` is that the arrow size is in plot units rather than "inches". You could probably fix that with some use of `xinch`.

Replace `lines` with `polygon` and specify a colour in the `...` args to get a solid arrow head.